# Weird transaction handling JavaEE 6

Tags: java, transactions, java-ee-6, optimistic-locking

Currently I study the JavaEE 6 transaction handling and I'm a little bit stuck.

I simulate a seminar booking engine where someone can book one or more persons on a seminar.
My entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Seminar {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    private Integer freeCapacity;

    ... //getters & setters
}
```

This is the EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class SeminarBooking {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    Event<Seminar> txListeners;

    public boolean bookSeminar(Long seminarId, int numberOfPersons) {
        Seminar seminar = em.find(Seminar.class, seminarId);
        Integer freeCapacity = seminar.getFreeCapacity();

        if((freeCapacity - numberOfPersons) >= 0) {
            //setting free capacity after booking 
            seminar.setFreeCapacity(freeCapacity - numberOfPersons);

            txListeners.fire(seminar);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

My transaction listener looks like this:

```
public class TxListener {
    public void onSuccess(@Observes(during=TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) Seminar seminar) {
        //omitted retrieving of minute,second,milli
        logger.fine("Successful booking -- " + minute + ":" + second + ":" + milli + " FreeCapacity: "+seminar.getFreeCapacity());
    }
}
```

The problem is, I'm hammering with 100 threads in parallel on the backend and getting log entries like this:

```
Successful booking -- 24:50:51 FreeCapacity: 9641
Successful booking -- 24:50:61 FreeCapacity: 9641
Successful booking -- 24:50:54 FreeCapacity: 9641
Successful booking -- 24:50:637 FreeCapacity: 9639
```

How can it be, that there are successful (committed) transactions with the same value of freeCapacity?

In my opinion the 2nd and 3rd transactions should throw an `OptimisticLockException`, because the 1st transaction has updated the version field of the entity. Therefore the 2nd and 3rd transactions should have been rolled back.

Do I miss something here? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry. I misread the question. The close vote is not deserved.

Comment: Could it be that the numberOfPersons you pass is 0?

Comment: @JBNizet The numberOfPersons is **always 2**.

Comment: According to the times that are printed - the listener's method invocations are certainly interleaved. I'm not acknowledged with this API, but... Are you sure it's the same `Seminar` instance?

Comment: And ... what happens if you set your seminar object to the explicit return value of merge, prior to firing your event? On a side note, this sort of scenario really does call for a pessimistic lock.

Comment: Well since you do not merge `seminar` back to persistent context, the changes you made go unnoticed by txmanager... anyway entity bean should implement Serializable, not that it would be the cause of your problem.